# Pure states in the proof of the Gelfand-Naimark theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I'm working through the original proof of the Gelfand-Naimark theorem (every abstract C* algebra is isometrically star-isomorphic to a C* subalgebra of the bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space), and I'm a bit confused on pure states.

Subsequent proofs require the linear functionals used (for the GNS constructed representations for the final direct sum) to be pure states, but I'm struggling to find which part of Gelfand and Naimark's proof implies this.

So my question is - what in the original proof implies the linear functionals used are pure states?

I'm very fresh on pure states so I have probably missed something pretty obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What in the original proof implies the linear functionals used are pure states?

Nothing. I cannot comment on the specific text you are reading since you don't say what it is. But pure states are irrelevant towards constructing the universal representation.

What you need to do to construct the universal represention is the following:

- first you show that states separate points. More specifically, given $a\in A$ there exists a state $\varphi$ such that $|\varphi(a)|=\|a\|$. This is achieved using the Gelfand representation.
- Then you construct the GNS representation for a single state.
- Then you construct the direct sum of all (unitary classes of) GNS representations coming from a state. Because the states separate points, this representation is faithful, and you are done.

There is not need for pure states in the above.

Comment: Thank you! I’m working from Gelfand and Naimark’s “On the imbedding of normed rings into the ring of operators on a Hilbert space” :)